# C Programming - Getting the Median from User Inputs

Tags: c

I need help fixing my code. What my code does it asking users to input a number multiple times and will terminate the program once -1 is entered. Then, will get the Sum, Max, Min, **Average** and **Median** values.

Sum, Min and Max seems to be working fine. But on the "Average" it's treating the -1 as a userinput, also, I need help on how to get the median value.

Here's what I got so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
char name[30];
int userInput;
int count = 0;
int sum = 0; // changed from 1 to 0
int max, min = 1000;
float average;

printf("Please enter your name: ");
scanf("%s", &name);

printf("Hello, %s, ", name);

do {
printf("Enter an integer (-1 to quit): ");
scanf("%d", &userInput);

if (userInput == -1) break; // I added this line, average works fine now

sum = sum + userInput;
count = count + 1;
average = sum / count;

if (userInput > max){
max = userInput;
}

if (userInput < min && userInput >= 0){
min = userInput;
}

}
while (userInput >= 0);

printf("Sum: %d \n", sum);
printf("Average: %.2f \n", average);
printf("Max: %d \n", max);
printf("Min: %d \n", min);

return 0;

}
```

Here's my sample output:

```
Please enter your name: A
Hello, A, Enter an integer (-1 to quit): 10
Enter an integer (-1 to quit): 20
Enter an integer (-1 to quit): 10
Enter an integer (-1 to quit): -1
Sum: 40
Average: 10.00
Max: 20
Min: 10
```

***So The rest seems to be working now after some modification except for getting the median value.***

Comment: `if(userInput == -1) break;`

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to increment the count when userInput == -1

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing the `count` and adding to the sum before checking whether `userInput == -1`. Try rewriting your loop:

```
while(1){
  printf("Enter an integer (-1 to quit): ");
  scanf("%d", &userInput);
  if(userInput == -1)
    break;
/* rest of loop body goes here */
}
```